# EyeGazeProvider null even after ensuring provider is available

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am trying to log the Vector3 corresponding to the eye gaze data on a Hololens 2.  My .csv output is fine in the editor, but running on the actual HL2, I can verify that my EyeGazeProvider is null, and thus, no data is being logged.  In the code below (a MS example script I'm modifying), I never enter the loop past the "eyeGazeProvider != null" check.

I've enabled the capability in Unity for EyeGaze and verified its in the .appxmanifest.  Also, I have both the XRSDK Windows Mixed Reality Eye Gaze Provider and its OpenXR counterpart as part of my Input Data Providers. I also have an EyeGazeInteraction profile, as is required.  I am truly stumped here.

[Gaze Providers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiMzd.png)
[OpenXr Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO5k4.png)

```
var eyeGazeProvider = CoreServices.InputSystem?.EyeGazeProvider;
            if (eyeGazeProvider != null)
            {
                gameObject.transform.position = eyeGazeProvider.GazeOrigin + eyeGazeProvider.GazeDirection.normalized * defaultDistanceInMeters;

                EyeTrackingTarget lookedAtEyeTarget = EyeTrackingTarget.LookedAtEyeTarget;

                // Update GameObject to the current eye gaze position at a given distance
                if (lookedAtEyeTarget != null)
                {
                    // Show the object at the center of the currently looked at target.
                    if (lookedAtEyeTarget.EyeCursorSnapToTargetCenter)
                    {
                        Ray rayToCenter = new Ray(CameraCache.Main.transform.position, lookedAtEyeTarget.transform.position - CameraCache.Main.transform.position);
                        RaycastHit hitInfo;
                        UnityEngine.Physics.Raycast(rayToCenter, out hitInfo);
                        gameObject.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Show the object at the hit position of the user's eye gaze ray with the target.
                        gameObject.transform.position = eyeGazeProvider.GazeOrigin + eyeGazeProvider.GazeDirection.normalized * defaultDistanceInMeters;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // If no target is hit, show the object at a default distance along the gaze ray.
                    gameObject.transform.position = eyeGazeProvider.GazeOrigin + eyeGazeProvider.GazeDirection.normalized * defaultDistanceInMeters;
                }
            }
```

Comment: As a test, could you try deploying the EyeTrackingDemo examples which is located at Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/EyeTracking/Scenes to your device?  Do you see the same behavior? This will help narrow down if it's an issue with your configuration or an issue with your scene.

Comment: Works fine.  Tracked eye gaze, but I didn't try to log anything.  The gray icon showed where I was looking as well.  It also does when I run my program, and I can gaze and select objects with the "pinch" gesture.  However, still not able to log.

Comment: For what its worth, I think I cracked it.  Wasnt the GazeProvider at all.  Its an issue with the way I am writing to my .csv.  Something to do with threading.  Appreciate the assist, the question helped get the juices flowing.